# Static variables end up in Doxygen docs when they shouldn't

Tags: c, doxygen

I've started using Doxygen for a C project.  I have set both EXTRACT_ALL and EXTRACT_STATIC to NO. Still, some of my file-level static variables show up in the documentation that Doxygen generates.

Of this block of definitions, `fps_ypos` and `fps_height` are included in the docs:

```
/* properties of the frames per second text */
static int fps_xpos, fps_ypos;
static int fps_length, fps_height;
static bool show_fps = FALSE;
```

`bool` is a typedef for `unsigned char`, if that matters.  This is MSVC C, not C99.

Anyone know what can cause this or what I can do to fix it?

By the way, I'm using Doxygen 1.7.5.1 on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure if it's intended behaviour or not, but as the two variables that are documented are second on the line, I'd suggest changing your code to this, i.e. splitting the declarations up to one per line, if you care enough about it:

```
/* properties of the frames per second text */
static int fps_xpos;
static int fps_ypos;
static int fps_length;
static int fps_height;
static bool show_fps = FALSE;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it!  Doxygen event lists the variables as static in the docs. It's a bit surprising given the age of Doxygen that this problem isn't either fixed or at least mentioned in their FAQ.

Comment: This surprised me as well, but I just checked and it is indeed a problem in doxygen (the static attribute is not copied to the second and later elements in the list). I'll correct it in the next release (1.7.6). For older releases use the suggested workaround.

Comment: Thanks! Doxygen is a great tool!

Comment: Wow. I see that 1.7.6 is out already, and the changelog confirms that the fix is included. Impressive!